# Is there a way to present top 5 and bottom 5 and the order by a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to present top 5 and bottom 5 and the order by a column?

I have 2 queries looking like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) 
         OG.GAMES AS 'Olympic Games', OC.CITY AS 'Hosting City', 
         OG.Expenses_Mil AS 'Financial Expenses (in multiples of 1M$)' 
     FROM 
         [Olympics].[Events_Facts] AS OEF 
     JOIN 
         [Olympics].[Games] AS OG ON OEF.GAMES_ID = OG.GAMES_ID
     JOIN 
         [Olympics].[Cities] AS OC ON OEF.CITY_ID = OC.CITY_ID
     ORDER BY 
         OG.Expenses_Mil DESC) A

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) 
         OG.GAMES AS 'Olympic Games', OC.CITY AS 'Hosting City', 
         OG.Expenses_Mil AS 'Financial Expenses (in multiples of 1M$)' 
     FROM 
         [Olympics].[Events_Facts] AS OEF 
     JOIN 
         [Olympics].[Games] AS OG ON OEF.GAMES_ID = OG.GAMES_ID
     JOIN 
         [Olympics].[Cities] AS OC ON OEF.CITY_ID = OC.CITY_ID
     ORDER BY 
         OG.Expenses_Mil) B
```

I want that the final output will order the expense column in a `DESC` order, but I can't operate on the nested column.

The output is:

```
2016 Summer Rio de Janeiro    10
2014 Winter Sochi              8.2
2012 Summer London             8
2002 Winter Salt Lake City     7
2004 Summer Athina             7
1900 Summer Paris              1
1904 Summer St. Louis          1
1906 Summer Athina             1
1912 Summer Stockholm          1.3
1920 Summer Antwerpen          1.4
```

while the desired output should be in a DESC order according the last column

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you mean display the *rank* of each row?

Comment: in the query above i want to union between a query that shows top 5 values (of og.expenses) and the bottom 5 values. and then to order the final expenses column with DESC order

Comment: How does `Events_Facts` come into this query, you are not selecting any of the columns? What are the relations between the tables, and why do you need `DISTINCT`, were you getting duplicate rows? Perhaps you should rethink your joins

Comment: `Events_Facts` is the connection table between the other tables. and `DISTINCT` is to get rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function `row_number() over()`.  If by chance there are ties, and you want to see them ... you can use `dense_rank()` instead

**Example**

```
with cte as (
SELECT OG.GAMES AS [Olympic Games]
     , OC.CITY AS [Hosting City]
     , OG.Expenses_Mil AS [Financial Expenses (in multiplies of 1M$)]
     , RN1 = row_number() over (order by OG.Expenses_Mil asc)
     , RN2 = row_number() over (order by OG.Expenses_Mil desc)
FROM [Olympics].[Events_Facts] AS OEF 
JOIN [Olympics].[Games]  AS OG ON OEF.GAMES_ID = OG.GAMES_ID
JOIN [Olympics].[Cities] AS OC ON OEF.CITY_ID = OC.CITY_ID
)
Select [Olympic Games]
      ,[Hosting City]
      ,[Financial Expenses (in multiplies of 1M$)]
 From  cte 
 Where RN1<=5
    or RN2<=5
 Order by [Financial Expenses (in multiplies of 1M$)] desc
```

**Just a side note:**  The window functions can be invaluable.  They are well worth your time getting comfortable with them.

Comment: this query gives incorreect output @john cappelletti

Comment: @Aby_g Not sure I can assist without more information.  It is your query.  Rather than doing a UNION ALL, we just rank the expenses (asc and desc).

Answer (score 0):

[@JohnCappelletti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70147233/14868997) is very good. However it does require two sorts, once for ascending and once for descending.

**Here is a solution that uses a single sort:**

We use `LEAD` with an offset to check if 5 rows later is missing.

```sql
with cte as (
  SELECT OG.GAMES AS [Olympic Games]
       , OC.CITY AS [Hosting City]
       , OG.Expenses_Mil AS [Financial Expenses (in multiplies of 1M$)]
       , RN = row_number() over (order by OG.Expenses_Mil desc)
       , ID5 = lead(OEF.ID, 5) over (order by OG.Expenses_Mil desc)
  FROM [Olympics].[Events_Facts] AS OEF 
  JOIN [Olympics].[Games]  AS OG ON OEF.GAMES_ID = OG.GAMES_ID
  JOIN [Olympics].[Cities] AS OC ON OEF.CITY_ID = OC.CITY_ID
)
Select [Olympic Games]
      ,[Hosting City]
      ,[Financial Expenses (in multiplies of 1M$)]
 From  cte 
 Where RN <= 5
    or ID5 IS NULL
 Order by [Financial Expenses (in multiplies of 1M$)] desc
```

Comment: your query looks good but there is no OEF.ID Column

Comment: OK you can use another column that is `NOT NULL`, preferably the primary key

Answer (score 0):

i found an original way to solve the problem with SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OLYMPIC_UNION_ORDERBY
AS  
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) OG.GAMES AS 'Olympic Games', OC.CITY AS 'Hosting City', OG.Expenses_Mil AS 'Financial Expenses (in multiplies of 1M$)' 
FROM [Olympics].[Events_Facts] AS OEF JOIN [Olympics].[Games]  AS OG
     ON OEF.GAMES_ID = OG.GAMES_ID
     JOIN [Olympics].[Cities] AS OC
     ON OEF.CITY_ID = OC.CITY_ID
ORDER BY OG.Expenses_Mil DESC) A

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) OG.GAMES AS 'Olympic Games', OC.CITY AS 'Hosting City', OG.Expenses_Mil AS 'Financial Expenses (in multiplies of 1M$)' 
FROM [Olympics].[Events_Facts] AS OEF JOIN [Olympics].[Games]  AS OG
     ON OEF.GAMES_ID = OG.GAMES_ID
     JOIN [Olympics].[Cities] AS OC
     ON OEF.CITY_ID = OC.CITY_ID
ORDER BY OG.Expenses_Mil) B
;

EXEC OLYMPIC_UNION_ORDERBY

CREATE TABLE  TempTable
(OUTPUT1 VARCHAR(MAX),
 OUTPUT2 VARCHAR(MAX),
 OUTPUT3 FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO TempTable
EXEC OLYMPIC_UNION_ORDERBY

SELECT * 
FROM TempTable
ORDER BY OUTPUT3
```